# php foreach looping off value from mysql row

Tags: php, html

I am looping through rows of mysql data as array's.

All the data goes into the labels fine as single values, yet when the edit button is used it does "updatecompany.php?id=1&id=2 when it should just be ?id=1 or ?id=2.

What am I doing wrong for that single field? Why is it pulling both values from the rows and not just one like the rest of the echo's.

```
  <?php
    $details = \Ar\login::getCompanys();
    foreach($details as $value){
      echo "<div class='container'><div class='well'>";
      echo "ID: " . $value['id'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Company: " . $value['name'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Logo: " . $value['logo'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Url: " . $value['site'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "EST: " . $value['est'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Info: " . $value['info'];
      echo "<br><br>";
      echo "<form action='updatecompany.php' method='get'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='". $value['id'] ."'/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>Edit</button>";
      echo "</div></div>";
      echo "<br>";
    }
    //print_r($details);
  ?>
```

Comment: You never close your `<form>` so you have one huge form with child forms.

Comment: that was the cause, jeez thanks man.

Comment: Okay, I've moved that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close your `form` so you are making multiple `form`s. You also don't need multiple `echo`s either. Something like:

```
echo "<div class='container'><div class='well'>
     ID: " . $value['id'] .
     "<br>
     Company: " . $value['name'] . 
     "<br>
     Logo: " . $value['logo'] . 
     "<br>
     Url: " . $value['site'] .
     "<br>
     EST: " . $value['est'] .
     "<br>
     Info: " . $value['info'] .
     "<br><br>
     <form action='updatecompany.php' method='get'>
           <input type='hidden' name='id' value='". $value['id'] ."'/>
           <button type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>Edit</button>
    </form> /* <-- guess */       
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>";
```

Should resolve the issue (the closing `form` location is a guess).

Answer (score 0):

```
</form>
```

Never closed the form out causing it to go nuts.

Answer (score 0):

you should close the `<form>` tag in your code. So your `form` line should look like:

```
echo "<form action='updatecompany.php' method='get'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='". $value['id'] ."'/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>Edit</button></form>";
```

Then you'll get the correct results.